# Join each element of one array to each element of other array in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, ruby-on-rails-3

I have two arrays and I can join them looping these two arrays. But is there better way of doing it?

```
colors = ['yellow', 'green']
shirts = ['s','m','xl','xxl']
```

Output required:

```
output = ['yellow_s','yellow_m','yellow_xl','yellow_xxl','green_s','green_m','green_x','green_xxl']
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using [`Array#product`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#method-i-product), you can get cartesian product:

```
colors = ['yellow', 'green']
shirts = ['s','m','xl','xxl']
colors.product(shirts).map { |c, s| "#{c}_#{s}" }
# => ["yellow_s", "yellow_m", "yellow_xl", "yellow_xxl",
#     "green_s", "green_m", "green_xl", "green_xxl"]

colors.product(shirts).map { |e| e.join("_") }
# => ["yellow_s", "yellow_m", "yellow_xl", "yellow_xxl",
#     "green_s", "green_m", "green_xl", "green_xxl"]
```

Comment: Alternatively `colors.product(shirts).map{|e| e.join("_")}`

Comment: @Candide, Thank you for suggesting the alternative. I added it to the answer.

Comment: Thank you Guys. I was not aware of this method.

Answer (score 0):

I used this method.

```
colors = ['green', 'yellow']
shirts = ['s','m', 'xl', 'l']
selection = []
x = 0
while x < shirts.length
  selections.push(colors.map{|c|c + "_" + shirts[x]})
  x += 1
end
selections.flatten!

=> ['yellow_s', 'green_s', 'yellow_m', 'green_m', 'yellow_xl', 'green_xl', 'yellow_xxl', 'green_xxl']
```